# Recalculate Data Cube in rptdesign

Tags: birt

Hello I have a problem which I would like to resolve.
I need different kind of groupings on "the same" data set. 
The way solved it is with a parameter that determines the grouping statement in the query and by resetting the parameter with JavaScript statements at various points in the rptdesign. 
It feels a it hacky, but it works for tables,
It does not however work for cross tabs/data cubes; there seems to be some kind of caching. 
Is there anyway to recalculate a data cube midway a report? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?
N.b. I really don't want to use separate data sets, I need dynamic grouping : )